# Dependency solver using std::future and std::async

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, future

I am trying to implement a simple dependency solver using `std::future` and `std::async`. Currenty I fail to understand is it even possible to do this. Question is, can we pass (not yet available) `future` to `async` call? If not, what actually can be done to have a chain of functions with some **not yet ready** input calling each other? Maybe, it is possible to override value passed to deferred async?

Probably my description is incomprehensible, so here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int adder(future<int> a, future<int> b) {
    return a.get() + b.get();
}

int main() {
    map<char, future<int>> scheme;

    scheme['c'] = future<int>(async(launch::deferred, [] { return 1;}));
    scheme['a'] = future<int>(async(launch::deferred, adder, move(scheme['b']), move(scheme['c'])));
    scheme['b'] = future<int>(async(launch::deferred, [] { return 3;}));

    cout << scheme['a'].get() << endl;
}
```

We should have a scheme like this:

```
c
  \
    a ----- result
  /
b
```

And a result of `4`.
This code fails: `move` just takes an empty `future` and pass it to `adder`. If we swap lines with `'a'` and `'b'` it will work fine, but this way we already should know dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use promises.  And maybe future futures.

```
template<class T>
struct problem {
  std::promise<std::shared_future<T>> p;
  std::shared_future<std::shared_future<T>> f;
  problem():f(p.get_future()){}
  template<class W, class...Args>
  void set(W&&work, Args&&...args){
    p.set_value(std::async(std::launch::deferred, std::forward<W>(work), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  }
  T get(){
    return f.get().get();
  }
};

int adder(problem<int>& a, problem<int>& b) {
  return a.get() + b.get();
}
int main() {
  std::map<char, problem<int>> scheme;

  scheme['c'].set([] { return 1;} );
  scheme['a'].set(adder, std::ref(scheme['b']), std::ref(scheme['c']));
  scheme['b'].set([] { return 3;} );

  std::cout << scheme['a'].get() << '\n';
}
```

There are probably easier ways.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce6ed65dab373f84).

Comment: Thanks, it really works! I understand almost all the magic behind future of future and promise of future. Here is a working version of code: https://gist.github.com/JIghtuse/25960e886d97ac885f67

Comment: @JIghtuse Added a live example.  I'm not sure if I can eliminate the future-future issue; maybe by explicitly storing a `std::function` in the `problem` to be set later, and then creating `std::shared_future` that invokes that function on a deferred basis?  Hmm, I think that will work, actually.  Things could get hairy if there are cycles, however.